# How to attach a value to the multiprocessing.current_process() in python?

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing

I have a python `multiprocessing` process which spawns subprocesses to run various commands. I want to wrap the process in another class which first terminates the subprocess if the parent process is terminated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def f():
  current_process = multiprocessing.current_process()
  current_process.subprocess = subprocess.Popen(...) # execute command taking a lot of time to run.

class ProcessWrapper(Process):
  def __init__(self, function):
    super(ProcessWrapper, self).__init__(target=function)

  def terminate(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'subprocess'):
      self.subprocess.terminate() # never gets here
    super(ProcessWrapper, self).terminate()

def main():
  p = ProcessWrapper(f)
  p.start()
  time.sleep(5)
  p.terminate()
```

The problem appears to be that the subprocess is never attached to the parent process. What is the reason for that? What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `hasattr` is a built-in function, not a method.  Your code will raise an `AttributeError` when executing `terminate`.

Comment: Your edit still won't work.  You want `hasattr(self, 'subprocess')`.

Comment: Fixed. That was a mishap from trying to post a shortened example of my  code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, let's use the following terms:  The "parent process" is the initial Python process you start; the "child process" is the process you start via the `multiprocessing` module; the "grandchild process" is the process you start via `subprocess.Popen`.

The issue is that your `f` is executed in the child process, but when you invoke the `terminate` method of the `ProcessWrapper` instance you're running code in the parent process, where a `subprocess` attribute was never assigned to the object returned by `multiprocessing.current_process()`.

To do what you want you could use [process groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) to enable the parent process to terminate the grandchild process directly, or (as a finer-grained, manual method) send a signal from the parent to the child and have a signal handler in the child terminate the grandchild.

Comment: Can you show me how to attach a handler to the child process to terminate the grandchild process?